# How to change the backgroundImage and innerHTML of a div when hovering over an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written a function that should change the background image of a div with id="image" to the current image that is being hovered. Also it should change the innerHTML to the alt text of the image.

I've written a function upDate(previewPic), that triggers whenever someone hovers (onmousover) over one of three images. Above the images is a div with id="image". The div should display the current image and alternate text.

However I can´t seem the get it working. What am I doing wrong?

```
function upDate(previewPic){
/* In this function you should 
1) change the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image" 
to the source file of the preview image

2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
to the alt text of the preview image 
*/

document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = 
url(previewPic.src);
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML =
previewPic.alt;
```

Here is my full work:

https://codepen.io/tastibit/pen/OZyNRw

Comment: It wants to be `'url('+previewPic.src+')'`.

Answer (score 0):

Your accessing the `backgroundImage` property which needs to be of type `string`. So simply wrap your code into quotations marks.

See the updated code:
https://codepen.io/Orlandster/pen/zjvBvE

Answer (score 0):

`style.backgroundImage` should be string

use ECMAScript 6 (ES6) introduces a new type of literal, namely [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

```
function upDate(previewPic){
 /* In this function you should 
    1) change the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image" 
    to the source file of the preview image

    2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
    to the alt text of the preview image 
    */
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = `url('${previewPic.src}')`;
  document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have updated and forked your [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjNKGb);

Effectively, you have to set the entire **"url('"+previewPic.src+"')"** portion in quotes.  I have also implemented the unDo().  Here is the excerpt from your codepen js;

```
/*Name this external file gallery.js*/

var imageDiv = document.getElementById("image");
var imageSrc = '';
var imageText = '';

function upDate(previewPic){
    /* In this function you should 
       1) change the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image" 
          to the source file of the preview image

       2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
          to the alt text of the preview image 
    */
    imageSrc = imageDiv.style.backgroundImage;
    imageText = imageDiv.innerHTML;

    imageDiv.style.backgroundImage =  "url('"+previewPic.src+"')";
    imageDiv.innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
  }

function unDo(){
     /* In this function you should 
        1) Update the url for the background image of the div with the id = "image" 
           back to the orginal-image.  You can use the css code to see what that original URL was

        2) Change the text  of the div with the id = "image" 
           back to the original text.  You can use the html code to see what that original text was
     */
     imageDiv.style.backgroundImage = imageSrc;
     imageDiv.innerHTML = imageText;
}
```

Comment: This answer helped me solve the problem. But instead of defining three variables I only define one. 

`var defaultText = document.getElementById("image").innerHTML;

 function unDo(){
  document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = "";
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "'"+defaultText+"'";
 }`